# using Reflection.PropertyInfo

Tags: vb.net, class

I need to loop through an object's properties and for each properties set 2 values.

for example say you have a car class:

```
 Class car
  Property Wheel1 As Wheel
  Property Wheel2 As Wheel
  Property Wheel3 As Wheel
  Property Wheel4 As Wheel
 End Class
```

and each wheel has a set of properties:

```
 Class Wheel
  Property size As Integer
  Property type As Integer
 End Class
```

is there a way to dynamically loop through an object that has wheels and set all of its wheels to size=5 and type=1.

this is where i got stuck trying to get it to work:

```
 Dim ThisCar As New car
  Dim Wheels() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = ThisCar.GetType().GetProperties()
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  Do Until i = Wheels.Count
   Dim TempWheel As Reflection.PropertyInfo = Wheels(i)

   Dim WheelProps() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = TempWheel.GetType().GetProperties()

   i = i + 1
  Loop
```

the `WheelProps` are not the properties off the wheel as required...

Comment: `TempWheel` is of type `PropertyInfo`. If you call the `GetType()` method, what do you think you will get? What does the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use TempWheel.PropertyType() instead of just TempWheel.GetType()
or you just set the Wheel like this:

```
foreach(var pInfo in typeof(car).GetProperties()
{
  if(pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Wheel))
  {
    // Get the value of existing wheel
    var wheel = (Wheel)pInfo.GetValue(ThisCar);
    Console.WriteLine(wheel.size);
    Console.WriteLine(wheel.type);

    // Set the value of wheel
    wheel.size = 5;
    wheel.type = 1;

    //pInfo.SetValue(ThisCar, new Wheel() {size = 5, type = 1}, null);
  }
}
```

But why don't implement car with a `List<Wheel>`?

Comment: can I get the size and type value for each wheel too?

Comment: Yes, you can get it from (Wheel)pInfo.GetValue(ThisCar);